# Kaddish Nusach Ashkenaz person waits for additions of Nusach Edos Hamizrach

Tags: kaddish, tzibur-community, nusach-ashkenaz, nusach-edot-hammizrach

A synagogue follows Nusach Ashkenaz (NA). For Kaddish Yosom, there are people who would normally daven Nusach Edos Hamizrach (NEM). The NA people stop their kaddish where necessary to let the NEM people insert their additions.

What do the sources say as to whether this behaviour

is worthy achdus

or transgresses the issur of  [לעשות אגודות אגודות](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9C%D7%90_%D7%AA%D7%AA%D7%92%D7%95%D7%93%D7%93%D7%95) do not make different groups.

Comment: Which behavior are you asking about? The NA people waiting are no different than waiting for someone else who is saying Kaddish slower than they are. All they’re doing is waiting quietly. They are not making agudos. Are you asking about the ones doing the inserting? Of course they are. If the shul is NA then they have to follow that nusach regardless if they like it or not.

Comment: Good. What would you say on an occcasion that I witnessed where the NA waited and indicated by gestures etc. that the NEM people ahould make their inserts?

Comment: @Chatzkel Or they're just following the pesak of Rav Ovadia: המתפלל עם אשכנזים והוא בתוך י”ב חודש לאב או לאם, ואומר קדיש לע”נ אביו או אמו, אין לו לשנות מהנוסח המקובל אצלינו, הן באמירת ויצמח פורקניה ויקרב משיחיה, וכן בחייכון וביומכון וכו’, והן באמירת יהא שלמא, ועל ישראל. https://www.yalkut.info/%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9F-%D7%9C-%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99-%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A9-%D7%95%D7%90%D7%96%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%94/

Comment: @JoelK they would be mistaken. That’s because they didn’t read the whole piece so they misunderstood. He’s talking about when one is saying it ALONE. in the next line he says אולם אם אומר קדיש יהא שלמא בבית כנסת של אשכנזים עם אחרים, [ואינו אומר את הקדיש לבדו], רשאי לקצר בנוסח יהא שלמא, כפי מנהג נוסח האשכנזים, כדי שיסיים ואמרו אמן עם כולם.

Comment: @Chatzkel Nope. If saying with others then he only says to keep יהא שלמא shorter. He would still want them to say ויצמח פורקניה

Comment: @JoelK I assumed that the question was about the additions of NEM not nusach sfard. That’sa whole discussion and almost universally accepted not to change the minhag hamakom. Why would R Ovadia make a difference between the two? He’s probably just talking about the additions of NEM without getting into the other differences but there’s no reason for the Halacha to change

Comment: @Chatzkel That's not how I read it. He ideally wants you to say the full EM nusach in an Ashkenazi shul. He lists where that is different to the ashkenazi version ויצמח, בחייכון וביומיכון, יהא שלמא, על ישראל. The only time he says not to is for יהא שלמא if you're saying with someone else - as a practical matter so that you get to ואמרו אמן together. He's not worried about לא תתגודדו and therefore he would tell you to keep all of the other differences in the kaddish

Comment: Check out שו"ת יחוה דעת ג:ד. (I can't find it anywhere online.)

Comment: @Cha you're answering if they are incorrectly changing from the minhag hamakom, not if they are causing agudos. the nafka mina is a shul without a fixed minhag (or more commonly, a shul that's generally ashkenazi but allows alternate kaddish nusach). can it allow this or is that a problem of agudos? It's worth rethinking this in the context of pronunciation: is a shul that allows some to say kaddish with a ת /s/ and some with a /t/ causing agudos, even if the shul allows people to pronounce hebrew however they want? (Some shuls only allow ת /s/ and they are entitled to that minhag hamakom)

Comment: @DoubleAA isn't changing minhag hamakom the same as making agudos? A shul that has no minhag hamakom, it wouldn't be considered agudos. At least that is what I understood with tefillin on Chol Hamoed, where some shuls just let everyone do whatever they want.

Comment: @Chatzkel I don't think those are the same. consider https://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php/%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%93%D7%99%D7%94_%D7%AA%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93%D7%99%D7%AA:%D7%9C%D7%90_%D7%AA%D7%AA%D7%92%D7%95%D7%93%D7%93%D7%95#.D7.91.D7.9E.D7.A0.D7.94.D7.92.D7.99.D7.9D

Comment: Worth noting as well that while the OP said it is a Nusach Ashkenaz shul, if the shul allows these sefardim to use their nusach, then the shul is really an almost-Nusach-Ashkenaz shul and Chatzkel's original comment wouldn't apply.